# How to test Redis server-assisted client side caching

Tags: redis

I want to enable Redis server-assisted client side caching. but im not sure how to test whether it works.
I set

```
redis-cli -a psswrd -n 1
CLIENT TRACKING on
```

and not sure if i should set it for other namesapces (2, 3) as well or it applies to all namespaces. and dont see any info on how to check CLIENT TRACKING value. I tried

```
CONFIG GET CLIENT TRACKING
```

CLIENT TRACKING is not in the list.
So how can i see if this feature works or not?